# Transform server status data to running 24 hour tabular format

Tags: sql-server, xml, linq, c#-4.0

I need to display running server status, in an asp.net grid view using c#, for the last 24 hours in 5 minute increments. The data is in SQL Server records of the form:  HostName, RecordDate, RecordTime, Status. I need to transform the data into tabular format to load a grid view control. Transform to something like: HostName, Date, 00:00 status, 00:05 status, ..., 23:55 status. One of the problems, of course, is the user can access the web page at any time. The column names must be the 5 minute increment time, as 15.30, 15.35, etc. They'll always be the same, as 24 hours will be displayed, but will be in a different order, and potentially cross dates, depending upon when the user logs into the web site. I hope I've explained this well enough. All options are on the table: linq, linq to sql, linq to xml, etc.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I will offer a T-SQL solution.  You need a date table that holds the 5-minute intervals for the day in question.  Left join that with your AccessLog (or whatever it's called) table where the access time is within each time range, and do whatever aggregations you want.  This will give you the vertical list.  Then you need to PIVOT that to make your TimeRanges into columns (search for SQL server PIVOT operator).

Below is the rough SQL.  After that, you just need to wrap the results into a pivot.

```
declare @myDate SMALLDATETIME = '20130415';

;with TimeRanges as (
    SELECT  TOP 288 DateAdd(minute, (Row_Number() over (order by sc1.Name) -1) * 5 , @myDate) TimeRangeMin
            , DateAdd(minute, Row_Number() over (order by sc1.Name) * 5 , @myDate) TimeRangeMax
    FROM    Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1, Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2
)
select  convert(varchar(5), TimeRangeMin, 114) AS TimeRange, COUNT(*)
from    TimeRanges t
        LEFT JOIN AccessLog a on a.AccessTime >= t.TimeRangeMin and a.AccessTime < t.TimeRangeMax
GROUP BY convert(varchar(5), TimeRangeMin, 114);
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Plus one just for the cool sql.  I have the last 24 hours of data in a table. My data loader does that. It has the host name, record time, record date, and status. The record time will always be a multiple of 5 minutes and the data in only dumped in 5 minute intervals. IOW, it will always end in a 0 or 5. I guess I just need to PIVOT as you suggested so I get the record time as the name for each column and the status as the data for each of the columns. I'll do some research on that. Thanks again.